# Dataflow issue with special characters like ä while ingestion into BQ (Issue with different accents)

Tags: java, google-bigquery, encoding, google-cloud-dataflow

I am facing an issue with API ingestion into BQ using dataflow. In dataflow, I am extracting the content and passing it into BQ, without doing any parsing. However, it reaches into BQ like the below:

[image]

Whereas the word should be the actual "Zählerablesung". This particular behavior occurs when I execute dataflow with a runner as 'DataflowRunner' not with 'direct'. I have seen a similar thread and thought of going with UTF encoding. So I modified the code a bit.

```
@ProcessElement
        public void processElement(OutputReceiver <String> receiver) throws IOException, ParseException {
            if (this.conn.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.conn.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                String output;
                output = new String(output.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

                while ((output = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(output);
                }
                in.close();
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response.toString());
                jsonArray.iterator().forEachRemaining( jsonObject -> receiver.output(jsonObject.toString()));
            }
        }
```

Still, I am not seeing any difference. Any help would be appreciatable

Comment: What makes you think that charset is UTF-8 and not, say Latin1? `String response = new String(this.conn.getInputStream().readAllBytes(), "Latin1");` might be worth trying

Comment: The fact that there are two unicode replacement symbols (`�`) suggests multiple encoding issues. Latin1 interpreted as UTF-8 would only show one symbol.

Comment: @g00se I am getting the words in German, that's why I decided to go with UTF-8

Comment: The language has nothing to do with it. Best to find out what's going on with the stream. Replace the `if` block with this and let us know what it prints: `HexFormat hf = HexFormat.ofDelimiter(" ");byte[] buff = new byte[16];int count = -1;try (InputStream in = conn.getInputStream()) {while ((count = in.read(buff)) > -1) {System.out.printf("%16s = %s%n", new String(buff), hf.formatHex(buff));}}`

Comment: I am getting values like this:



:00","Notificati = 3a 30 30 22 2c 22 4e 6f 74 69 66 69 63 61 74 69

onsEnabled":true = 6f 6e 73 45 6e 61 62 6c 65 64 22 3a 74 72 75 65

,"createdDate":" = 2c 22 63 72 65 61 74 65 64 44 61 74 65 22 3a 22

Comment: I was expecting you to pick out the German bits ;)

Comment: @g00se it's very difficult to do that. Because I am getting normal English as well in the same node, so I can't predict after seeing the hex code, which one is German and which one is not. I can do that after comparing, but that requires reading the input stream first.

Comment: Well you could look for *Zählerablesung* for one. Which OS are you using?

Comment: @g00se the whole execution is in linux, ubuntu

Comment: Good. So run at the console using that code and do `java your-app.jar | tee /tmp/out.log` and we can examine that file. One of the first things you could do with it is `grep -B 1 -A 1 'blesu' /tmp/out.log`. You might get lucky with that.

Comment: @g00se When i run the code in a console, there is no issue of encoding. When I run it as a DataflowRunner, it will be running in a ComputeEngine. This will be created at runtime, there I am facing the issue. I even created a similar VM and ran the code in it after ssh, and it ran fine and console logs showed no encoding problem. The out put was like:

{"IsEdited":true,"Original_Time_Spent":1,"NotificationsEnabled":true,"Entity":{"EntityType":{"EntityTypeName":"Task"},"EntityNotes":"Monatliche Zählerablesung ","EntityTitle":"Zählerablesungen",".......

Comment: OK so that's a start. If there are no errors in the console then you have proven that the *source* is UTF-8. It looks like, as @Kayaman has already hinted, that the destination is at fault. I just wanted to be sure you were starting at least with the correct encoding. Looks like the destination for some reason is expecting a 7/8 bit encoding. So far we haven't been told much about that destination though

Comment: @g00se I have found a solution. I was trying different approaches. I can't explain it completely, because I don't have much encoding knowledge. I am adding that as part of the answer. Please have a look. Thanks for helping though. Your way of breaking down the problem helped me here.

Comment: Good. I can't explain that ;) More direct would be `JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(new String(conn.getInputStream().readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));`

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution here. It's having no much difference from the problem apart from the that I have added an iteration over the response. Also, I removed an extra encoding step, which was there in the problem statement.

```
 @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(OutputReceiver <String> receiver) throws IOException {
        if (this.conn.getResponseCode() == 200) {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.conn.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            String output;
            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
            while ((output = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(output);
            }
            in.close();
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response.toString());
            Iterator<Object> iterator = jsonArray.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()){
                Object obj = iterator.next();
                receiver.output(obj.toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Now I can see the data as in the original format in BQ:

[image]